# replace .. with . in R

Tags: regex, r

How can I replace .. with .

I tried something like:

```
names(dataset) <- gsub("[/./.]",".",names(dataset))
```

But it doesn't work as I hoped.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try adding `fixed = T`

```
R> c <- "v.."
[1] "v.."
R> gsub("..", '.', c, fixed = T)
[1] "v."
```

Comment: ...but it's a good idea to avoid defining variables like `c`, `t` etc since they are also (common) functions...

Comment: @Tommy, good point - and I probably should have written out `TRUE` instead of `T`.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have your slashes in the wrong direction, and you need to double them:

```
gsub("\\.\\.",".",names(dataset))
```

Fixed to reflect comments.

Comment: I think you mean `gsub("\\.\\.","\\.",names(dataset))` and also you don't need the double slashes for the substitution you could just put `gsub("\\.\\.",".",names(dataset))`

Comment: In general, follow the Dalgaard rule: If you believe you had sufficient backslashes, double them.